# How to make a trigger(insert,update) to check if rows are equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Use a trigger (update and insert) to prevent the insertion of two incompatible components into the same assembly, regardless of the order in which they are added.

I have a table Order with columns OrderID and ProductID, and another table Compactibility with 3 columns of type nvarchar to check compactibility.

How can I make a trigger to compare products with the same OrderID and check the strings
(Edit: This is not the full database, just the data that matter)

```
CREATE TABLE Compactibility(
  IDProduct int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES
  Produto(IDProduto),
  Caixa nvarchar(50) NOT NULL CHECK (Caixa IN  ('ATX', 'Micro-ATX', 'ALL')), 
  Socket nvarchar(50) NOT NULL CHECK (Socket IN ('LGA2066','LGA1700', 'A76M', 'NONE')),
  TipoRAM nvarchar(7) NOT NULL CHECK (TipoRAM IN ('NONE','DDR4','DDR5')),
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Order(
  IDOrder int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1),
  IDProduct int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product(IDProduct)
)
GO
```

Comment: I would suggest you should use tables for things like Sockets, RamType, CaseType. Then you would make foreign keys to this table. Consider how painful this design is going to be once a new type of RAM is released. If you have things properly normalized all you have to do is add a row to the RamType table and everything will just work.

Comment: Can you trigger on inserts to Compactibility? In the trigger code check to see if the product ID is also present in any orders in the Order table.

Comment: I had a table for each component but I had few time and was my first sql project soo I made ot a bit simplistic

Comment: I never did a trigger properly that my biggest difficulty. I did a select with the values but didn't had the knowledge to make a trigger to compare the strings of the components with the same order ID

Comment: Using triggers to enforce referential integrity is a very clear sign that something has gone the wrong direction with the design. Triggers can be useful but not to ensure the data is correct. That is what constraints are for.

Comment: "check the strings" is not clear enough. Check them in what way?

Comment: Also, if something is "compactible", that means you can squeeze it to make it smaller. If things will be able to work together, they are "compatible".

Comment: Is it your intention to prevent multiple `Order` with the same `IDOrder` and `IDProduct`? (Example: An order for 2 widgets, 3 thingamabobs, plus 1 more widget.) What is your intended behavior should a duplicate occur? If you just want to fail the insert, you can place a `UNIQUE` constraint on those two columns. Anything else might best be handle from the application side. While an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger could possibly detect a dup product and update the existing count instead of inserting a new record, I don't think putting such logic in a trigger is a good design practice.

Comment: Sometimes one doesn't want to use foreign keys or have complex validation requirements. While it's often best to do it on the front end, one *can* use insert/update triggers and just rollback transaction to prevent things from being added based on som rules. The data being added is available in inserted/deleted pseudo tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE db_TI1;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER tr_c
ON ProdutoVenda
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @IDProduto1 INT, @IDEncomenda INT, @IDProduto2 INT, 
            @Caixa1 NVARCHAR(50), @Caixa2 NVARCHAR(50), 
            @Socket1 NVARCHAR(50), @Socket2 NVARCHAR(50), 
            @TipoRam1 NVARCHAR(50), @TipoRam2 NVARCHAR(50);

    SET @IDProduto1 = (SELECT TOP 1 IDProduto FROM inserted);
    SET @IDEncomenda = (SELECT TOP 1 IDEncomenda FROM inserted);
    SET @IDProduto2 = (SELECT TOP 1 IDProduto FROM ProdutoVenda WHERE IDEncomenda = @IDEncomenda AND Montagem >= 1 AND IDProduto <> @IDProduto1);

    IF @IDEncomenda IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @Caixa1 = (SELECT Caixa FROM Compactibilidade WHERE IDProduto = @IDProduto1);
        SET @Socket1 = (SELECT Socket FROM Compactibilidade WHERE IDProduto = @IDProduto1);
        SET @TipoRam1 = (SELECT TipoRAM FROM Compactibilidade WHERE IDProduto = @IDProduto1);

        SET @Caixa2 = (SELECT Caixa FROM Compactibilidade WHERE IDProduto = @IDProduto2);
        SET @Socket2 = (SELECT Socket FROM Compactibilidade WHERE IDProduto = @IDProduto2);
        SET @TipoRam2 = (SELECT TipoRAM FROM Compactibilidade WHERE IDProduto = @IDProduto2);

        IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM Compactibilidade 
            WHERE (Caixa = @Caixa1 AND Caixa = @Caixa2) 
              AND (Socket = @Socket1 AND Socket = @Socket2) 
              AND (TipoRAM = @TipoRam1 AND TipoRAM = @TipoRam2)
        ) 
        
        AND @IDProduto1 = @IDProduto2 
        AND @Caixa1 = @Caixa2  OR @Caixa1 NOT IN ('ALL') OR @Caixa1 NOT IN ('ALL')
        AND @Socket1 = @Socket2  OR @Socket1 NOT IN ('NONE') OR @Socket2 NOT IN ('NONE')
        AND @TipoRam1 = @TipoRam2 OR @TipoRam1 NOT IN ('NONE') OR @TipoRam2 NOT IN ('NONE')
        
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Componente Incompatível!', 16, 1);
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END
    END
END;
GO

UPDATE ProdutoVenda SET IDEncomenda = 1766 WHERE IDProduto = 1
SELECT *
FROM ProdutoVenda
```